# Most important things to know in ROS?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and Linux, so the command line interface is tricky for me to understand. As a beginner, I am wondering what everyone's tips are for the best things to know about ROS, important features, or valuable commands. I have recently purchased a TurtleBot and I am exited to get started with robotics.

-Parker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10978/most-important-things-to-know-in-ros?/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My own suggestion is try to run basic parts of ROS tutorials, and then focus the area which has tutorials to make some progress.

Basic : http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

All : http://www.ros.org/wiki/AllTutorials

If you have anything doesn't know just google and find similar questions.

if getting no answer then question here again.

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-23**:
If you don't see an answer, SEARCH through the answers.ros.org community FIRST, and then ask again.